# How to show nested LI element horizontally?

Tags: html

i have a structure of my menu like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a /></li>
        <li><a />
            <ul>
                <li><a /></li>
                <li><a /></li>
                <li><a />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a /></li>
                             ....
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Also, I have 4 divs floated left to each other. 
Onclick, I would like to show items inside li in the next corresponding div to the right. 
How do I do this in jquery?
One thing I did is hard coded, and it loses my nested li completely when I click other parent.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/W2FJd/

Comment: you should use a CSS file instead of putting your styling in the HTML for each element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**css file**

```
.inlineDisplay{

display:inline

}
```

**html**

```
<li class="inlineDisplay>inline</li>
<li class="inlineDisplay>inline</li>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BQKqN/) is an example

Answer (score 0):

After you clean a bit your css :D...

To display list elements on the same line:

```
li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```